# Double-click ad unit lookup for div failed (DFP error)?

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager

Just added double-click DFP ads to a friend's site. Realized that only one of four ads are appearing. Although the status of all 4 ads are "active", 3 are not appearing.

I ran the DFP debugger and got this output:

```
Ad unit lookup for div div-gpt-ad-1327994622973-0 failed.
Div div-gpt-ad-1327994622973-0 is not mapped to a known ad unit.
```

It doesn't appear to be a javascript issue, but the code for these ads was taken directly from the "generated tags" and these units are active. This occurs in multiple browsers.

Could this be a caching issue? How can a cache buster be implemented for ads only? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't seem to have extensive documentation on the causes, but when you have more than one DFP ad on the same page, you MUST modify the code in your `<head>` and avoid using the individual code generator with each ad unit because it will alter the ad IDs each time.

**Easy Steps**

1. under inventory select "generate tags" under the left column nav
2. you will now see a list of ad units
3. select ALL ad units and generate all at once
4. copy the head code into the head area of the page
5. copy the body code for each ad into the proper area of the page.

**Important Notes**

- Include all ads in both `<body>` and `<head>`
- Generate all ad tags at once, not individually